# How to get existing value from form to another magento 1.9

Tags: forms, grid, magento-1.9, adminhtml

I have two different forms , one including user information and the second one have a grid. What I need to do is to get the email from first form to use it in the controller of the 2nd, there is a way or I need to get the value again from database?

Comment: Can you please post some code of your forms?

Answer (score 0):

you can try sending the email value through ajax when it is set to the other controller by adding parameters in the url or u can store email in a table(hope both tables are for same product or customer) and load it in other form using the id.

Hope it helps....

Comment: Yes what I did is to get data again from the table getting a collection.